# JQuery slide wait variable not setting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused as to why this is not working, please could someone point me in the right direction? I have wrote some JQuery to slide down a submenu. However when moving the mouse around the menu it will fire thousands of events I am trying to have it wait for a hide to finish before doing another slidedown. However this does not seem to work:

```
$("li.title").children('ul').hide();
var hidden = true;

$("li.title").hover(
    function() {
        if (hidden == true){
        var height = $(this).children('ul').height() + $(this).height();
        $(this).height(height);
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
        var hidden = false;
        }
   },
   function() {
        $(this).height(25);
        $(this).children('ul').hide(function() {
        var hidden = true;
        });
   }
);
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and a jsFiddle.net example if possible?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML? Or Fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `var` from your `hidden` variable within the callback functions in hover. You're reassigning those variables locally, so its not listening to the global `hidden` variable.

Change this:

`var hidden = false;`

to this:

`hidden = false;`

Comment: Fantastic reply, this seems to have done the job. Now one more question, it is still firing before the other event has finished. I was hoping the variable would fix this, do you know anyway to have it wait until the hide has finished?

Comment: Try setting `hidden = false` before you call `$(this).children('ul').slideDown()`. That may work, otherwise you could probably do something utilizing the `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` events in jQuery.

Comment: @SimonStaton I made some changes to my answer that should work using timeouts.  I didn't test it so it may need to be tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `var`.  The problem is you are creating a new instance of `hidden` scoped to your callback functions and not seeing the global `hidden`.

```
$("li.title").children('ul').hide();
var hidden = true,
    myTimeout;

$("li.title").hover(
    function() {
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
          if (hidden == true){
            var height = $(this).children('ul').height() + $(this).height();
            $(this).height(height);
            $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
            hidden = false; //Removed var here
          }
        },100);
   },
   function() {
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).height(25);
        $(this).children('ul').hide(function() {
        hidden = true; //and here
        });
        },100);
   }
);
```